# Jetty 9 not able to load jndi datasource driver class

Tags: jetty

I searched for the issues for several days and could not find out what can fix the problem.  Please help.

I have the standalone web app with jetty-9.3.10.v20160621 and the datasource is defined in jetty.xml.
I have put the jars into the JETTY_HOME/lib/ext.

But it still failed to start the application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:758)
```

I also tried with jetty-env.xml and which had the similar issue that the class loader could not find the class even though the jars shown in the classpath.

Comment: the jars I put into the server /lib/ext are: commons-dbcp2-2.1
commons-logging-1.2
commons-pool2-2.3
ojdbc6

Comment: Are you using maven? If so, can you paste the output of `mvn dependency:tree`. I suspect you have an older version of jar in the dependency tree and because of this reason its nto referring the jars you referenced in `/lib/ext`

Comment: Thank you, harshavmb.  I ran the dependency:tree in eclipse and did not find any issue with the jars.. Please help to see if I missed any problem: